# Change CSS value of other elements if one element is being hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a few social-media links displayed by `.card` box-elements. Now I want to make that if no `.card` is hovered, the opacity will just stay at `1` but if one `.card` is hovered, every card except for the one that's actually being hovered, should now change its opacity to `0.7`. My `.card`s just have the classes `card socialsElement`.

I've already tried this

```css
.socialsElement.card:hover .card:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

but doesn't work

*(Expectation)*
[If none is being hovered](https://ibb.co/612gN0C)
[If One card is being hovered](https://ibb.co/Lh3hQBq)
[Live Preview](https://316a-2003-c2-af41-d600-e07c-d067-b1f3-bd84.ngrok.io/socials/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin 1em;
  background: navy;
}

section:hover div {opacity:.7}

section:hover div:hover {opacity:1}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: @DNAScanner, happy to help! BTW, you might want to avoid change of opacity when the section is hovered but no divs are. Let me know if you have any difficulties with that.